# Azure ARM throws bad request for storage connection string during template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I'm creating an azure storage account,key vault and adding the storage account access keys as a secret to the key vault. I dont see any issues with the ARM code but when I deploy this in Azure I get a bad request for the connection secret.

```
 {
            "condition": "[equals(parameters('storageAccountOption'), 'new')]",
            "name": "[variables('storageaccountuniqueName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            }            
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('kvname')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
            "properties": {
                "enabledForDeployment": false,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
                "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                        "objectId": "[parameters('kv_owner_id')]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "secrets": [
                                "all"
                            ]
                        }  
                    },
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[variables('tenantId')]",
                        "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', variables('adfname')), '2018-06-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [],
                            "secrets": [
                                "list",
                                "get"                                
                            ]
                        }
                    }                    
                ],
                "sku": {
                    "name": "standard",
                    "family": "A"
                }
            }            
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(variables('kvname'), '/', variables('kv-stg-secretname'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageaccountuniqueName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('kvname'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageaccountuniqueName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageaccountid'), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
            }
        }
```

I've set the dependencies for the keyvault secret to ensure it's done only after storage account and key vault is deployed. This is the deployment error from Azure. I'm using service principal with Azure Cli to deploy this, so the kv_owner_id is passed from cli as the service principal client id.

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the overview of the deployment operations as seen from the portal. Except for the conn string secret everything was created successfully.

[image: deployment operations]

Comment: As mentioned in the error message, have you tried listing deployment operations? That might give you some information about the error you're getting.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've updated in the ticket the deployment operations . Except for that connection string everything is good.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the complete template? It will be easier that way to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define the `storageaccountid` variable? You could use the standard `resourceId()` reference in `listKeys`:

```
"properties": {
    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageaccountuniqueName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageaccountuniqueName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
}
```

Comment: I've just used another variable for the getting the resource ID ->  "storageaccountid": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',variables('storageaccountuniqueName'))]" , both do the same. I've tried the way you have mentioned too. It didnt work though

Comment: Ok. So at this point, since the snipped you posted looks correct, having the full template would help (as mentioned above).